# chrome コンソールで [native code] と表示されたときに定義をみたい

Tags: javascript

chrome コンソールで [native code] と表示されたときに定義をみたいです。

```
ƒ () { [native code] }
```

のような返り値の関数の定義を確認するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

本家StackOverflowに[同様の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103336/read-javascript-native-code)がありましたので、これを元に回答します。

Chrome（やFirefox）における`[native code]`のような関数は、Javascriptで定義されたもの**ではなく**、CやC++などで記述されたものです（このため、`native`と表現されています）。

このため、Javascriptでの定義というのは存在しませんが、ブラウザのソースコードを読むことでその実装を確認することができます。

参考：Chromiumのソースコード
http://src.chromium.org/viewvc